# Connecting a webform with an Access 2007 database in a remote server

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, database-connection

I have little experience working with servers and web applications. The objective is to create a web portal were users can enter employee data and be able to retrieve it later on to print etc. 
I have created the html file(have also saved it as "hr_form.asp") that has the form: Input fields and submit button etc. I want to be able the information entered in the input fields stored in the access db when the user clicks the "Submit" button. I will be using Access 2007; I have the access db file with the fields corresponding to the web form (fname, lname, assignment, etc). 
The access db is currently saved in my workstation but will need to be moved to a remote server.

My idea which consists of placing the connection string within the "hr_form.asp" to connect to the access db locally (before attempting to connect to the remote server), then finding a way to request the information from the form via the post method and saving the user input in the appropriate field in the access db.

But then I heard that Visual Studio Web Developer is a good tool and that the connection can be done through a wizard option...

Can someone please provide me with their personal approach to this and if you don't mind, a small step-by-step overview of the process ? I have searched and all the responses I've come across assume the has experience and skip some steps. Thank You

Comment: Will this be Intranet or Extranet access?

Comment: It is to be used by some individuals in the HR department in the school district so I believe is Intranet.

Comment: best solution here would be to use SQL Server, even Std edition.  Do you have access to a Standard edition SQL Server, or even MySQL?

Comment: Yes, the remote server has SQL Server and I have access to it.  Thanks, now that I think about it is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

easier to obfuscate the connection string with a SQL Server than Access.

As well, should the need arise, connecting to a SQL Database is alot easier to connect to if you have an Intranet SharePoint Site Collection than an Access Database.

Comment: Umm is probably not a good idea but I went ahead and did everything using Access. To test, I decided to do this locally first. So, I went ahead and set up the local DSN connection and selected the Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) and gave it a name.

Comment: My main form (hr_form.html <form action="save_to_db.asp" method="post"> and the save_to_db.asp contains the connections Dim name, lname etc... Dim dsn, conn, sSql,... name= Request.Form ("lname").... and so ; dsn ="dsn=newhire" Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") conn.Open dsn sSql = "INSERT into tablen (name,lname) values ('" & name & "','" &fname&"') ... conn.execute(sSql) conn.close() Set conn = Nothing    I placed my files in the wwwroot folder and I'm able to access the html page through localhost but when I click submit nothing happens :S

Comment: @user1308665 Using Access to design is not a Bad idea.  Just understand that Access macro's (visual or VBA) will not always translate to SQL Transaction scripts.  Just make sure, mentally, on DB design you know that Access Field types are not equal to MS-SQL field types.  Edit your original post with the updated text for future reference.  I always like to append an Edit section when getting my question answered.

Comment: @user1308665 in regards to the Submit button not performing any actions, submit the code-behind segment and html form design code so we can review it for any potential errors.  Problem with using localhost sometimes causes problems when publishing to public addresses versus dev-environment address.